# Desktop Application that Downloads RSS Feeds as PDFs

Tags: windows, linux, macos, pdf, ebook

I'm looking for a application (preferable desktop) that will periodically and automatically convert selected news feeds and/or websites into PDF, suitable for viewing on any ebook reader.

Something like [Tabbloid](http://www.tabbloid.com/), but that can output fiels to a specific folder (Tabbloid emails them) and produced output suitable for viweing on an ebook reader (Tabbloid's PDFs are optimized for printing, and won't display on certain readers ... like the one I own)

Does such a beast exist? OS X prefered but Windows or *nix will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a [**RSS2PDFF** site](http://rss2pdf.com/),
got that from [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/116381/convert-rss-to-pdf).

- There is also [**FeedJournal**](http://www.feedjournal.com/)
- More at [**36 Top PDF Converter Tools**](http://www.technobuzz.net/pdf-converter-tools/).

---

- Since you are interested in ebook readers
  (no RSS ref here I guess),
  another useful link: [**eBook Conversion Matrix**](http://www.ebooktechie.com/conversion/ebook-conversion-matrix/)

Comment: Damn you keep posting good answers +1

Comment: @Ivo, Thanks for the appreciation `:-)`